# Ignoring file extensions

Tags: git

I just encountered a situation where my .gitignore was ignoring folders that contained ".lib" because of a rule intended to ignore files with the extension .lib.

My .gitignore had "*.lib" as a rule, and there is a folder called "Main.Lib" that was also getting ignored.

How do I make sure only files with the extension .lib are ignored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ending `/` means *directory*. And a line beginning with an exclamation mark means *not*.

And since later lines have precedence, this `.gitignore` will do what you need:

```
*.lib
!*.lib/
```

Comment: Ok, so essentially to make sure I'm not unintentionally ignoring folders, I have to do this for every file extension I ignore

Answer (score 1):

Use `!` to *unignore*

```
 *.lib
 !Main.lib/
```